# ASP.NETでinput要素のnameが勝手に「ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder」になる

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

原因はマスターページを使用しているからだそうで、
ContentPlaceHolderに「ClientIDMode="Static"」を書けば直ると海外サイトには書かれていました。
しかし、これを記述しても直りません。

マスターページのページディレクティブ、ContentPlaceHolder要素の属性、コンテンツページのasp:Content要素の属性内、さらには対象のinput要素の属性にまで書きましたが直りません。

何か対処方法が間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: ASP.NETのバージョンは4.0以上でしょうか？

Comment: 具体的にaspxのコードを記載してください。“input要素”とは、ASP.NETのTextBoxコントロールですか？

Answer (score 2):

`name`属性に対応するのは`UniqueID`プロパティですので、`ClientIDMode`の設定は`name`には影響しません。
なお`ClientID`プロパティは`id`属性に出力されます。